# Copy Item from One static list to another and revert as well

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-mobile, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two lists. `ListOne` and `ListTwo`. There are 1-5 items in `ListTwo` and want to Drag the desired item to `ListOne`, which will be blank initially, that item will be added to `ListOne` but that Item will not be removed from `ListTwo`. I have completed till here.

Problem : When I want to drag the Item from `ListOne` to `ListTwo` this item should be removed from `ListOne` but should not be added to `ListTwo`. This is not happening.

In simple words I want ListTwo to be static.

Here is my fiddle link.http://jsfiddle.net/hQnWG/1596/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution.  I connected sortable1 to sortable2 and used a receive handler on sortable2 to remove the item when it's moved over.

```
$(function() {
    $("#sortable2").sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable1",

        helper: function (e, li) {
            this.copyHelper = li.clone().insertAfter(li);

            $(this).data('copied', false);

            return li.clone();
        },
        stop: function () {

            var copied = $(this).data('copied');

            if (!copied) {
                this.copyHelper.remove();
            }

            this.copyHelper = null;
        },

        receive: function(e, ui){
            $(ui.item[0]).remove();
        }
    });

    $("#sortable1").sortable({
        connectWith: "#sortable2",
        receive: function (e, ui) {
            ui.sender.data('copied', true);
        }
    });

    $("#sortable1").on("click", "li", function () {


    });   
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jufcd4y8/